# Create executable from API .py to .exe, that when the .py is executed in the console, parameters are sent to it

Tags: python

I need to create a Python API executable, when I run the API through the console I pass the parameters I need, how can I create the Windows executable by passing the parameters that the API needs?
Here I leave the code with which I run the API from the console: 
`python api.py --shape-predictor eye_predictor.dat --dataset ../images --encodings encodings.pickle`

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: in this moment is Windows, but when i run the api is in ubuntu

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I already managed to create an .exe but without the necessary parameters that the API needs to run correctly